# Select card from saved cards, if not create a new card Before Payment in Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Select card from saved cards, if not create a new card Before Payment in Laravel Cashier.

Note: Just Charging the $N amount, N can be different for next time checkout.

Step 1: List of Saved Cards, if not create a new one.

Step 2: Choose Card

Step 3: Checkout the payment.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$defaultCard = $user->defaultCard();  // Default Card

$cards = $user->cards();   //List of Cards


//Make current source as default
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(($request->stripe_id));
$customer->default_source = $request->card_token;
$customer->save();

// Now charge customer
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                'amount'   => $amount,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'customer' => $customer->id,
            ]);
```

Comment: cards() method is now paymentMethods()

Answer (score 0):

Find `Billable.php` trait in `laravel/cashier/scr/` and search word like `card` then you find all methods related to card i.e.

- hasCardOnFile()
- fillCardDetails()
- updateCard()
- updateCardFromStripe()
- deleteCards()
- cards()
- defaultCard()

Use them according to your requirements

Comment: defaultCard() method is now defaultPaymentMethod()